# How to Time Analysis

Tags: c++, time, analysis

I had to write code for a function that uses a loop to compute the sum of all integers from 1 to n.
I also need to do a time analysis, counting each basic operation (such as assignment and ++) as one operation. I need help with understanding how to count each basic operation. Is int computeSume(int n) one step, which is C1? The for loop is that multiple steps?
Please help explain. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Create a function that uses a loop to compute the sum of all integers from 1 to n.

//Create Function
int computeSum(int n)
{
    //create sum variable
    int sum = 0;
    
    //create for loop
    // i must be <= to n so it will count all integers and not cut the last int off.
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
        //return statement
        return sum;
}

//Main Method
int main()
{
    //Input varibale
    int n;
    
    //Create user prompt
    cout << "Enter a value: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "The sum of all integer from 1 to " << n << " is " << computeSum(n) << "." << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int op_count = 0;` Every time you do a basic operation, do `++op_count;`

Comment: See `std::accumulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this peace, I commented out the necessary information for your reference.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int computeSum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;        // One unit time.
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)        // Condition will be checked N+1 times so n+1 unit time.
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
        
    return sum;     // One unit time.

    // Total units of time is N+3, which is nothing but O(N).
}

//Main Method
int main()
{
    
    int n;          // Declaring a variable is one unit time.
    
    cout << "Enter a value: " << endl;      // One unit time.
    cin >> n;           // Depends how much time you take to enter value, But for simplicity taking as 1 unit.
    cout << "The sum of all integer from 1 to " << n << " is " << computeSum(n) << "." << endl;     // It could have been taken only a simple statement with one unit time.
                                                                                                    // But computeSum(n) is a function so, we first analyse it's time.
    
    return 0;       // one unit.
}
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. If you breakdown the `for` loop, you'll notice that it has one assignment operation (for `i=0`), and for each step `i` is incremented. This will not modify the final answer (it is, indeed O(n)), but according to the question, your analysis lacks a few considerations.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but, I tried to make it simple and understandable, as in the final we just have to calculate the Order of time our program is taking.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. I knew the answer had to O(n) but I wasn't sure as to how you count the for loop.